# SQL with 3 conditions with join: "where X in(foo)", "where X not in(foo)", or no "where" rule

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

I am trying to create a query where, depending on a variable, results included are a result of one of three conditions:

```
1) WHERE am.process     IN (SELECT process_name FROM it.special_processes)
2) WHERE am.process NOT IN (SELECT process_name FROM it.special_processes)
3) (equivalent of no WHERE clause for the process)
```

This query works for condition 1:

```
SELECT info.sortingorder sort, info.stage, SUM(am.qty) boh
FROM it.snpshot am, it.info info, it.naming nm
WHERE info.stage = nm.stage(+)
AND am.process  IN (SELECT process_name FROM it.special_processes)
GROUP BY info.sortingorder, info.stage
```

This works for the condition 1 or, depending on :flag, condition 3:

```
SELECT info.sortingorder sort, info.stage, SUM(am.qty) boh
FROM it.snpshot am, it.info info, it.naming nm
WHERE info.stage = nm.stage(+)
AND :FLAG = 1 OR am.process IN (SELECT process_name FROM it.special_processes)
GROUP BY info.sortingorder, info.stage
```

However, when I want to handle condition 3, things get complicated. I tried something like:

```
SELECT info.sortingorder sort, info.stage, SUM(am.qty) boh
FROM it.snpshot am, it.info info, it.naming nm
WHERE info.stage = nm.stage(+)
AND :flag = 0    -- (this is for condition 3)
OR (:flag = 1 AND am.process     IN (SELECT process_name FROM it.special_processes))
OR (:flag = 2 AND am.process NOT IN (SELECT process_name FROM it.special_processes))
GROUP BY info.sortingorder, info.stage
```

...But I get:

```
ORA-01719: outer join operator (+) not allowed in operand of OR or IN
*Cause:    An outer join appears in an or clause.
*Action:   If A and B are predicates, to get the effect of (A(+) or B),
           try (SELECT WHERE (A(+) AND NOT B)) UNION ALL (SELECT WHERE (B)).
Error at Line: 5 Column: 19
```

The error message attempts to give some advice, but I don't see how it applies to a set of conditions like shown above (conditional UNION ALL). Removing the outer join (+) eliminates the error, but it's there for a reason.
The complexity is starting to explode (especially considering the above is a distillation of a much larger query) and I already have an SQL "NOT IN()" which I usually see as a red flag.
My previous approach was to dynamically generate the "NOT IN" or "IN" part of the query string, but that always seemed like an awful hack. Note: PL/SQL is not an option for various reasons.

My question is: How would you handle this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'd lose the old outer join syntax and rewrite using ANSI (that might get rid of your error message right off the bat - it's a shortcoming of the old (+) syntax). I'd then try to incorporate CASE logic in the where clause (untested):

```
SELECT info.sortingorder sort, info.stage, SUM(am.qty) boh
FROM it.snapshot am
   , it.info info LEFT JOIN it.naming nm ON info.stage = nm.stage
WHERE CASE WHEN 
           (:flag = 1 AND am.process IN 
              (SELECT process_name FROM it.special_processes)) THEN 'Y'
           WHEN 
           (:flag = 2 AND am.process NOT IN 
              (SELECT process_name FROM it.special_processes)) THEN 'Y'
           WHEN :flag = 0 THEN 'Y'
           ELSE 'N'
      end = 'Y'
GROUP BY info.sortingorder, info.stage;
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you're just missing up your logical ands and ors here.

```
SELECT info.sortingorder sort, info.stage, SUM(am.qty) boh
FROM it.snpshot am, it.info info, it.naming nm
WHERE info.stage = nm.stage(+)
AND (:flag = 0    -- (this is for condition 3)
OR (:flag = 1 AND am.process     IN (SELECT process_name FROM it.special_processes))
OR (:flag = 2 AND am.process NOT IN (SELECT process_name FROM it.special_processes))
)
GROUP BY info.sortingorder, info.stage
```

Now all the terms are and-ed together. Previously, you were missing one set of (); I have added it after the word "and" before the :flag = 0 and before the group by. Believe that'll get you by. Do you see why? true and false and false or true = true.

Comment: I'm not sure that order of precidence is as your describe.  I believe that the OR's will have precidence, then the AND's.  Much like `A + B * C * D` = `A + (B * C * D)`.  Additionally, I'm not sure that an error in the business logic would account for a compilation error?

Comment: @Dems: Try the following: `select * from dual where 1 = 2 and 1 = 2 or 1 = 1;`.  As you'll see the `and` is resolved before the `or`.

Comment: My question had the error Jesse described, but the original (much larger) query does not. I guess I didn't do a very good job of making an example query for SO. Thank you for the catch.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd try very hard to get this into an IF block, and write the three versions of the query; the EXPLAIN PLAN for 'conditional' queries such as these tends to be pretty poor...

What happens if you change your notation to explicit JOINs?

```
SELECT
  info.sortingorder sort,
  info.stage,
  SUM(am.qty) boh
FROM
  it.snpshot am
CROSS JOIN
  it.info    info
LEFT JOIN
  it.naming  nm
    ON info.stage = nm.stage
WHERE
       (:flag = 0)   -- (this is for condition 3)
    OR (:flag = 1 AND am.process     IN (SELECT process_name FROM it.special_processes))
    OR (:flag = 2 AND am.process NOT IN (SELECT process_name FROM it.special_processes))
GROUP BY
  info.sortingorder,
  info.stage
```

**EDIT**

This may or may not help your error, but may yield a better EXPLAIN PLAN...

```
WHERE
  CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM it.special_processes WHERE process_name = am.process)
       THEN 2 ELSE 1 END
  <>
  :flag
```

- flag = 0 => unequal (true) always (CASE never returns a 0)
- flag = 1 => unequal (true) if am.process exists in it.special_processes
- flag = 2 => unequal (true) if am.process doesn't exist in it.special_processes

Answer (score 0):

My solution for "no where clause" typically is to supply a predicate as such:

```
WHERE 1 = 1
```

Since it always evaluates to true, it should have no impact when included, even alongside other predicate conditions. I have, however, seen it change the query execution plan in Microsoft SQL Server.